# Why does urllib.parse not split the the URL <scheme>:<number> correctly in all cases?

Tags: python, url, path, urllib, url-scheme

If I input a URL of the form `<scheme>:<integer>` then neither function splits off the scheme correctly depending on the scheme being used. If I alter `<integer>` by adding a non-digit character this works as expected. (I'm on python 3.8.8)

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse("custom:12345")  # does not work
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='custom:12345', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse("zip:12345")  # does not work
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='zip:12345', params='', query='', fragment='')
urlparse("custom:12345d") # this works  as expected
ParseResult(scheme='custom', netloc='', path='12345d', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse("custom:12345.")  # so does this
ParseResult(scheme='custom', netloc='', path='12345.', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse("http:12345")  # for some reason this works (!?)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='', path='12345', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse("https:12345") # yet this does not
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='https:12345', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse("ftp:12345")  # no luck here neither   
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='ftp:12345', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

According to Wikipedia, a URI requires a scheme. Empty schemes schould correspond to [URI references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#URI_references), which should only treat `<scheme>:<number>` as a schema-less (relative) path containing a colon if it is preceded by `./`.

So why does this break in the way demonstrated above? What I would have expected is that all the cases above split the URI/URL into a `<scheme>:<number>` where `<number>` is the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing different results if there are non-numerical characters in the path because of [this section](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/154f86f056c0f68cadd310e68fd2855f9fc9a5a8/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L453-L458):

```py
# make sure "url" is not actually a port number (in which case
# "scheme" is really part of the path)
rest = url[i+1:]
if not rest or any(c not in '0123456789' for c in rest):
    # not a port number
    scheme, url = url[:i].lower(), rest
```

In Python 3.8, if the input has the form `"<stuff>:<numbers>"`, the `numbers` are assumed to be a *port*, in which case the `stuff` isn't treated as a scheme and it all ends up in the path.

This was reported as [a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue27657) and (after quite a lot of back and forth!) [fixed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5a88d50ff013a64fbdb25b877c87644a9034c969) in Python 3.9; the above was rewritten to simply:

```py
scheme, url = url[:i].lower(), url[i+1:]
```

(and some special casing for `url[:i] == 'http'` was removed).